# Download spacy model and get AttributeError 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ndarray'

Tags: python, spacy

I'm new on python spacy package.

I wanted to download model 'en_core_web_sm' and I get AttributeError.

I searched since 2 days all over the web and I couldn't fix it.

Someone can help me please ?

The code :

```
import spacy
nlp=spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
```

The error :

```
n = y.shape[0]

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ndarray'
```

I'm using Python 3.6 on conda environment (spyder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened to me once during development and the reason was that for some reason, my code tricked spaCy into thinking I was on GPU. On GPU, spaCy uses `cupy` instead of `numpy` – and if `cupy` is not installed, it [defaults to `None`](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/compat.py#L27). It's likely that the code should be calling `numpy.ndarray`, but it's calling `cupy.ndarray`, i.e. `None.ndarray`, which results in that error.

If you've intended to run spaCy on GPU, make sure it's available and you've [installed](https://spacy.io/usage/#gpu) the correct dependencies for your CUDA version. If you're running spaCy on CPU, here are some things to try:

- Check what's installed in your environment and make sure you didn't accidentally end up with a half-broken install of `cupy` or something like that. Also make sure `numpy` is installed correctly.
- Unsatisfying answer, but often helps: uninstall spaCy and its dependencies, and reinstall the latest version, ideally in a clean virtual environment.